# MonoDevelop: Autosave being asking many many times

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

With MonoDevelop 2.8.6.4 I am getting asked many many times a day if I would like to load a file from AutoSave even though there was no crash and the files were closed properly. The only way around it for a little while is to delete the MonoDevelop 2.8 cache folder over an over again.

Is there a work around for this bug as it's very time consuming to work with.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this was fixed a while back and the fix will be in an upcoming MonoDevelop release. It's triggered by having the "format on save" preference enabled.